# Google Play - same package name won't upload the app

Tags: android, google-play

I`m trying to upload a new version of my application on Google Play and getting the following error message

> Google Play sending apk failed - must have same package name

I created a "new project" since I migrated it from Eclipse to Android Studio, but the package name is **exactly the same**.

What could possibly be going on?

Comment: It`s an update. Not a new app.

Comment: What about the keystore file?

Comment: It was exactly the same keystore, same package name.

Answer (score 0):

Silly bug.

Found a solution: *clearing* the cache data from Google Chrome did the job.

Also, the `applicationId` that you can find at `gradle.build` must be the same name of the `package`.